# Log4net logfile is not created in release mode for winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, log4net, log4net-configuration

I added the config in Assembly.cs

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

here is my configuration

```
   <configSections>
   <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections> 
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="GetWorkLog.txt" />
  <!--C:/logs/my_log_file.log-->
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
  <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

how to fix this issue?

Comment: What does your app.config look like? Are you registering log4net module anywhere?

Comment: @mariocatch updated the question, log file is generated in debug mode, it not working in release mode.

Comment: Add to the log4net node `debug="true"` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to embed the configuration data in the .config file the section name must be identified to the .NET config file parser using a configSections element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="INFO" />
            <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Source: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#dot-config

Comment: file is generated in debug mode, its not working in release mode

Comment: @GANI try calling XmlConfigurator.Configure(); from the startup of your app. Do that in lieu of the attribute configuration that you have now.

Comment: its working by adding this XmlConfigurator.Configure(), and creating logfile in bin folder. I added config to insert the loginfo to database, this is not working in release mode.How to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, the log4net worked fine before then it stopped all of a sudden.
After a few hair pulling, I discovered that another app was using the log file.
Without going into details of how my other application was using the same log file. 
**Make sure that NO other application is using the log file, log4net is trying to write to.**